# Вывод поля ACF в подкатегориях

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Создал поле

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывел названия подкатегорий и записи этих подкатегорий. Мне нужно чтоб у подкатегорий слева была иконка. Для иконки и добавил поле. Пытался вывести разными способами но что-то не понимаю как. Никак не выводится

Вот весь код вывода

```
 <?php
            query_posts("cat=46");
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                $k = get_the_category($post->ID);
                if ( $k[0]->cat_ID == $cat ) {
                    echo '<li><a href="'; the_permalink(); echo'" rel="bookmark">';
                    the_title();
                    echo '</a></li>';
                }  endwhile; else:
                echo '<p class="podcat">Upss</p>';
            endif;
            ?>

            <div class="already-items">
                <?php
                $current_cat = get_query_var('cat');
                global $ancestor;
                $childcats = get_categories('child_of='.$current_cat.'&hide_empty=0&orderby=id');
                foreach ($childcats as $childcat) {
                    if (cat_is_ancestor_of($ancestor, $childcat->cat_ID) == false){
                        echo '<div class="already-item">
                    <div class="already-item_img">
                        <img src="';?><?php get_field('Icon-podr', $childcat->cat_ID); ?> <?php echo '" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <span>';
                        echo $childcat->cat_name . '</span>
                </div>';
                        $mycat=get_the_category(); $mycat=$mycat[0];
                        $postslist = get_posts('posts_per_page=-1&category='.$childcat->cat_ID);
                        ?>

                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                        <? $ancestor = $childcat->cat_ID; } } ?>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы можете получить поле для определенной категории используя вариант получения поля для определенной категории для этого есть несколько вариантов передачи параметра в get_field(). в вашем случаем это будет примерно вот так

```
?>
<div class="already-item">
    <div class="already-item_img">
        <img src="<?php the_field( 'Icon-podr', 'term_' . $childcat->cat_ID ); ?>" alt="">
    </div>
    <span><?php echo $childcat->cat_name; ?></span>
</div>
<?php
```

подробнее об этом я бы советовал вам почитать по этой ссылке https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

так же у вас полно проблем с код стайлом подробнее вы можете ознакомится по этой сслыке https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/

и еще я бы советал вам почитать о функции query_posts() и по возможности быть аккуратнее с переопределением главного запрос!

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/